# JavaFx: Error on item remove

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I have the following that is called the a delete button is pressed:

```
   @FXML
private void handleDeleteCall() {
    int selectedIndex = callTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
        callTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
    } else {
        // Nothing selected.
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.initOwner(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());
        alert.setTitle("No Selection");
        alert.setHeaderText("No Call Selected");
        alert.setContentText("Please select a call in the table.");

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

This was working perfectly until I added the following code that I'm using to filter tableview data.

```
   public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    // Add observable list data to the table
    callTable.setItems(mainApp.getCallData());
    FilteredList<Call> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getCallData(), p -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Compare first name and last name of every person with filter text.
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

            if (person.getBillingNumber().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches first name.
            } else if (person.getCallStart().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches last name.
            }
            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });

    // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList. 
    SortedList<Call> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

    // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(callTable.comparatorProperty());

    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
    callTable.setItems(sortedData);
```

Now when I try to delete an item I get the following error.

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
    at telecom.view.CallOverviewController.handleDeleteCall(CallOverviewController.java:142)
    ... 62 more
```

All of the above code is in my controller class. Please let me know if you have any idea on how to fix this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace not just the first line :)

Comment: I'm kinda new to all this. What do you mean the 'stack trace'? The error message?

Comment: Yes the complete error message.

Comment: Edit your answer to do that. The comments can't be formatted

Comment: Just added it. Is that enough? Thanks for your help by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the data from the underlying list rather than the filtered one.

```
Call selectedIndex = callTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
if (selectedIndex != null) {
    mainApp.getCallData().remove(selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! So this works. The problem now is that the first line is getting the index of the filtered list because it's looking at the callTable in the view. But when it goes to do the delete, it's delete the item in the original list at the index. Does that make sense?

Comment: If your items are unique, you should be able to use the selected item reference rather than an index, e.g. use getSelectedItem() and remove(selectedItem), rather than getSelectedIndex() and remove(selectedIndex).

Comment: You guys are Java gods. Thank you so much for your help. What is the best way to ensure that an item is selected? Before I was doing selectedIndex >= 0.

Comment: Just (selectedItem != null) seems to work...But is it good practice? Seems a tad too...Open ended.

Comment: Ofc you can modify it to fit your eventual needs.